# Gatling Integration with JENKINS without using MAVEN

Tags: jenkins, gatling

1. Developed few scripts using GATLING tool
2. Able to execute those scripts as a standalone basis

   - Execution done through GATLING provided .bat file
   - Triggering of the batch file will ask for user inputs during run time to 
     select which scenario to simulate
3. Trying to integrate these scripts and trigger via JENKINS -

   - As parameterizing the argument does not support the GATLING provided bat 
     file
   - Configuring the GATLING provided bat file results in failure of build - 
     as it requires a user input during run time

Please anyone can provide a step wise approach to integrate GATLING scripts in JENKINS

Answer (score 0):

1. Gatling support passing parameter : http://gatling.io/docs/current/cookbook/passing_parameters/
2. Gatling seems a Java tool and execute script by a .bat/.sh file, so that you can inspect what command and parameters it used in backgounnd sence with some tool's help. like 'processhacker' is a enhancement of Windows Task Management. with it you can see the whole command to help you find out how to pass scenario you want to run in command line. If 'processhacker' can't help that,  you need to read the souce code of Gatling or send support mail to its company to ask help.